# Redirect to route

Tags: symfony, annotations

I want some routes to "exists", but to redirect to another route.

For example, this is what I did with the `/` route

```
/**
 * Homepage exists but redirect to projet
 *
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function indexAction() {
    return $this->redirectToRoute('projet_index');
}

/**
 * @Route("/projets/", name="projet_index")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function indexAction() {}
```

The thing I want to know is if it's this the best method to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope the best way to do that is simple as that:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 * @Route("/projets/", name="projet_index")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function indexAction() {
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: I know this method (should have written it in my question), but it won't change the URL. If I go to homepage route, the URL will be and stay /. What I want is, if I go to homepage route, the URL should be /projets/. Thanks though

Comment: In this case you should go for your solution, it's totally valid.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat off-topic, but there's a somewhat dirty trick you can use in a similar scenario, where you want to have several URLs resolving to a single route, using [placeholders with requirements and default values](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#giving-placeholders-a-default-value):

```
/**
 * @Route("/{path<projets/|>?}", name="projet_index")
 */
public function someAction() {
    // ...
}
```

The way it works is by defining an optional placeholder (with the `{...}` syntax) called "path" (though you can call it something else). That placeholder is given requirements with the `<...>` syntax: it can be either `"projets/"` or the empty string `""`. Therefore, both the `"/"` and the `"/projets/"` URLs match that route, and nothing else, as they're off the form `"/{path}"` with a path placeholder that matches its requirements.

So far, so good. But there's still one thing we need to do: give it a default value with the `?`, otherwise methods like `redirectToRoute` or the Twig function `path` will complain that we aren't given them a value for all the placeholders. Note that you could also use `"/{path<projets/|>?projets/}"` to make the default value URL `"/projets/"` instead of `"/"`.

I know it's not exactly what OP wanted, but I think it can be a useful trick to know, and someone having a question similar to OP's might find it useful.